# Citing a hyperlink in References using Bibtex

Tags: bibliographies

I have written my bibliography in `bibtex`. I want to include one reference for which only the hyperlink is known. How can I do that? I am using following commands for adding Bibliography

```
\bibliography{paper1}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

Comment: I would say: `url` - field?